# macOS Mojave 10.14 apache-tomcat-9.0.13 gives error when running in eclipse 2018-09 (4.9.0)

Tags: eclipse, macos-mojave, tomcat9

Facing issue as mentioned in 'Title', tried all related answers like updating the WTP, and removing section from 'Apache -> arguments -> VM Arguments' in Eclipse Tomcat configuration: 
" 
-Djava.endorsed.dirs="/usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.13/endorsed
"
Now, it runs [as opposite to that when that the above fraction of part of VM Arguments], it now gives 404

Answer (score 0):

well, server is actually working correctly (after the -Djava.. part is removed for every new server added), but the 404 error was due to missing index.html 
Thanks